# Not able to run reactjs code on hackerearth

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, jsx

[Sample code in image i tried to run on hacker earth. I wanted to run react with hook. But before that I am stuck with understanding and making it work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWe4r.png)

Can smeone help me understand how this works and how I can write all react jsx code in this portal

Comment: Hello and welcome to the StackOverflow. May I suggest you take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to improve your question?

Answer (score 0):

I got answeer. Hacker earth support react by changing javascript language to babel/es6 and . Add library in html for react. Sometime changes are not reflected immediately